# Simple way to return anonymous types (to make MVC using LINQ possible)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'd like to implement MVC while using LINQ (specifically, LINQ-to-entities).  The way I would do this is have the Controller generate (or call something which generates) the result-set using LINQ, then return that to the View to display the data.  The problem is, if I do:

```
return (from o in myTable select o);
```

**All** the columns are read from the database, even the ones (potentially dozens) I don't want.  And - more importantly - I *can't* do something like this:

```
return (from o in myTable select new { o.column });
```

because there is no way to make anonymous types type-safe!  I know for sure there is no nice, clean way of doing this in 3.5 ([this](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx) is not clean...), **but what about 4.0?  Is there anything planned, or even proposed?**  Without something like duck-typing-for-LINQ, or type-safe anonymous return values (it seems to me the compiler should certainly be capable of that), it appears to be nearly impossible to cleanly separate the Controller from the View.

Comment: When you are working with a orm you should get used to the thought of having the sql select all columns of a table. If you write queries that selects only a few you might just as well be using sql in the first place. If you have dozens of properties on your objects then that is your problem. Your objects should be smaller and you should think about how you can fix that. Anonymous types should not be passed around, specially not as models to a view.

Comment: @Mattias: Unfortunately, life is not so simple.  For example, consider the case where I select a few columns from different tables, including an array of objects selected using an inner-LINQ query.  As far as I'm aware, there's no way to return that as a single EF object - it *has* to be a new type, and defining a new concrete type for every query like this is ridiculously cumbersome.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a pretty bad model. Your object should have the references that it needs and you can just use the "Include()" method in EF (to eagerly load that data). If you stop thinking about the data as different columns in different tables, and more about your model (more OO) it will most likely be a lot easier to work with. Bottom line: If you feel the need to pass around anonymous types you are most likely doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one even attempted to answer my question, I will answer it myself..

It turns out, C# 4.0 supports duck-typing - they call it [dynamic typing](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx).  However, in using dynamic types to return anonymous types, we lose the benefits of strong types:

- Compile-time type-checking
- Performance
- Intellisense

I've opened a feature request to have strongly-typed anonymous return types [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542278/ability-to-return-strongly-typed-anonymous-classes#) - if you think this would be a useful addition to C# 5, follow the link and let the .Net team know!

Answer (score 4):

Use a view model layer.  Your view has to know what it is going to display.  I guess its possible to create a view that just formats a multi-dimensional array of data, but that isn't exactly the best reason to go with an MVC solution.  You can however populate a view model with an anonymous object for consumption in your view.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous types are primarily designed to be used within a method.  They are not suitable for communication between methods.

If you need to pass a set of data between two functions the best way is to create a new type wrapping the data or use a loser grouping like `Tuple<T1,T2>` or `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`

Comment: with the exception of a reflection based scenario, in which case there are a couple of good uses for them (in the MVC framework html helpers for example)

Comment: @Jared: Except that with LINQ, that's not true at all - LINQ-objects are certainly meant to be passed around, but you just can't do it in C# due to language limitations.  It *can* be done in VB.net, however.

Comment: @BlueRaja, sorry that's incorrect.  They **can** be passed around in either language as `System.Object`.  They cannot be strongly passed around in either language as anonymous types are well anonymous.  They can't be defined directly in any place that would show up in metadata. In VB.net (and C# 4.0) you can work around this by accessing them in a weakly typed fashion but that is not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

I assume that you have an entity class for your table 'myTable' (let's call it 'MyTableEntity'), so why don't you instantiate a new MyTableEntity object and use object initializer to fill only those columns you want?

```
return (from o in myTable select new MyTableEntity { AColumn = o.column });
```

This will not translate to a SELECT * as you asked, but you'll still have a way to pass a strongly-typed object to a view.

You have to be careful to just make use of the initialized properties inside the view and that's it.

Does this makes sense for you?

Comment: That's a good idea - I'll try it out at work when I get a chance (not for a few days at least)

Answer (score 0):

On .NET 4.0 Anonymous types can easily be converted to ExpandoObjects and thus all the problems is fixed with the overhead of the conversion itself. 
Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception/5670899#5670899)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert anonymous types into dynamic objects, here is the simple implementation of [Donymous](http://www.codehunkit.com/snippets/5/dynamic-anonymous-type-wrapper-class-to-access-in/) objects (Dynamic anonymous objects) that can populate from Anonymous object or DataReader.