# Why can't an Anonymous Type be used outside the method it's created in?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I understand that if I cast it to a named type I can do whatever I want with it, but it'd make for much tidier code if I could keep the anonymity between method calls.

Comment: Duplicate (of one of [my questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450536/simple-way-to-return-anonymous-types-to-make-mvc-using-linq-possible) ).  @DaveDev: see also [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542278/ability-to-return-strongly-typed-anonymous-classes)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a duplicate based on the title - Your question explores ways to make it happen. My question is asking why.

Comment: The question presupposes a falsehood and therefore cannot be answered. Anonymous types are unified within assemblies. If you use the same anonymous type in two different methods in the same assembly, you *will* get the same type.

Comment: @Eric:  you would know better than anyone: would it be possible (feasible) to allow returning anonymous types, as in the [suggestion I linked above](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542278/ability-to-return-strongly-typed-anonymous-classes)?  If **you** say no, I guess I will have to stop my feverish campaigning...

Comment: @BlueRaja: I would love to do that, however, there are some points against. The first is that we now have a standard tuple type; the existence of a reasonable alternative is reason to not do a feature. Second, there is no CLI (and certainly no CLS!) standard for what an anonymous type looks like; we'd have to invent a way to standardize anonymous types so that they could be in public metadata. And finally: how do you document a method that returns an anonymous type?  Doing this opens up all kinds of cans of worms that have impacts not just across our division but across the industry.

Comment: @BlueRaja: Basically, I'm not saying that it is impossible; we all understand that this would be really nice. But I am saying that it has significant costs and design problems, and therefore has to be prioritized against other features that are competing for that budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the signature of your method as a contract.  Your method says **"I promise to return you something that contains the following fields."**  If you return an anonymous object from your method, there's no contract.  You're just saying **"There's some data here, good luck!"**

If C# 4 is at all an option, you can just use [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) to return somewhat more arbitrary data.

Comment: Same answer I gave to Ben:  It's certainly possible for the compiler to generate a class behind-the-scenes and use all the existing type-verifications afterwards...

Comment: @BlueRaja The Green Unicorn: It is possible for the compiler to figure that out behind the scenes, and (for example) F# compiler is able to figure out types from your code (or you get a type error).  Doesn't change the fact that the C# compiler (as of right now) doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

While it should be avoided because it isn't very clean, you might consider [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx) hack from Jon Skeet. However, if at all possible, it should be avoided.

Answer (score -2):

This is a guess...but I'm so "awesome" I'm "sure" I'm right...

Anonymous types really aren't "anonymous."  The class that represents the unknown type is generated at run-time local to the method call on the run-time stack(hence the method-only scope).  Returning from the function call(popping the stack) you lose all the objects in that scope including the anonymous class that was hiding on the stack with that method call.

Guessing over...

Comment: Anonymous types are generated at compile-time. The difference is that they are private to the scope they were created in.

Comment: Anonymous classes are generated at compile time.  http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx  That's why John Rasch's "cast by example" example works.

Comment: Sorry, your guess is wrong: Anonymous types are created at compile-time. You can verify this using Reflector. You can also pass and return anonymous type instances as `object` and play with them using reflection, but I wouldn't recommend it in production code.

Comment: @Rex M: They aren't private classes, they are `public sealed` (at least for now)