# Entity Framework 5 - Apply filter loading related entities using Include

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Ok I've two tables with me

```
    Candidates
    Id   Name 
    1    Tejas
    2    Mackroy

   Experiences
   Id  Designation CandidateId isDeleted
    1   Engineer        1         true
    2   Developer       1         false 
    3   Tester          1         true
    4   Engineer        2         false
    5   Tester          2         true
```

The model classes are :

```
    public class Candidate
    {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<Experience> Experiences { get; set; }
    }

    public class Experience
    {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string Designation { get; set; }
         public int CandidateId { get; set; }
         public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
    }
```

I wish to get  **GET ALL**  the candidates along with their Qualifications but only those where  **isDeleted == false** .

It'll be somewhat like  **_DbContext.Candidates.Include("Qualifications").ToList();**

So it'll be like :

**{ 1 , "Tejas" , { 2, "Developer" } }, { 2, "Mackroy", { 4, "Engineer" } }**

I wish to know how this can be implemented by directly using  **DbContext**  aswell as using  **Generic Repository** .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering inner collection with Entity Framework 5 and Repository pattern and Unit of Work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479352/filtering-inner-collection-with-entity-framework-5-and-repository-pattern-and-un) or http://stackoverflow.com/q/16798796/861716.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom view model and populate it with you data:

```
    public class  CandidateViewModel {

             CandidateViewModel() {
                Qualifications = new List<Qualifications>();
             }

             public int Id { get; set; }
             public string Name { get; set; }
             public List<Qualifications> Qualifications { get; set; }
    }

    public class Qualification {
             public int Id { get; set; }
             public string Label { get; set; }
    }
    //ViewModel

    var result = _DbContext.Candidates.Select(o => new CandidateViewModel {
                                  Id = o.Id,
                                  Name = o.Name,
                                  Qualifications = o.Experiences.Where(d => !d.IsDeleted).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is lazy loading it. Is there a way to eager load only the non deleted work ex?